# Problem on Matrix Calculus.

Tags: calculus, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

How do I find $$\arg\min_{\alpha \in\mathbb R^n} (K\alpha-y)^T(K\alpha-y)+\lambda \alpha^T K \alpha$$ using Matrix calculus ? Here $K$ is $n\times n$ matrix, $\alpha$ and $y$ are $n\times 1$ vectors, $\lambda$ is positive real number. I am completely new to Matrix Calculus, a solution might help me to relate with the Wikipedia's article on Matrix Calculus.

Answer (score 3):

Let's define a new variable $x=(Ka-y)$ and use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product $$A:B = {\rm tr\,}(A^TB)$$
Write the function in terms of this new variable. Then find its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= x:x + \lambda K:aa^T \cr
d\phi &= 2x:dx + \lambda K:(da\,a^T + a\,da^T) \cr
 &= 2x:K\,da + \lambda(K+K^T):da\,a^T \cr
 &= \big(2K^Tx + \lambda(K+K^T)\,a\big):da \cr
 &= \big(2K^T(Ka-y) + \lambda(K+K^T)\,a\big):da \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial a} &= 2K^TKa-2K^Ty + \lambda(K+K^T)\,a \cr
}$$
Set the gradient to zero and solve
$$\eqalign{
&K^TKa + \tfrac{\lambda}{2}(K+K^T)\,a = K^Ty \cr
&a = \big(K^TK + \tfrac{\lambda}{2}(K+K^T)\big)^{-1}K^Ty \cr
}$$
If $K$ is symmetric, this can be reduced to
$$a = (K^2 + \lambda K)^{-1}Ky$$
If $K^{-1}$ exists, it can be further reduced to
$$a = (K + \lambda I)^{-1}y$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
\begin{align}
F(\alpha)
=&
(K\alpha-y)^T(K\alpha-y)+\lambda \alpha^T K \alpha
\\ 
=&
\big(\alpha^TK^T-y^T \big)(K\alpha-y) 
\\
=&\alpha^TK^TK\alpha -\alpha^TK^Ty-y^TK\alpha +y^T  y
\end{align}
We have that $ DF (\alpha_0) = 0 $ implies $ \alpha_0 =\mathrm{argmin}_{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^n}F(\alpha)$ since $ F $ is convex.
\begin{align}
F(\alpha+h)
=&
(\alpha+h)^TK^TK(\alpha+h)-(\alpha+h)^TK^Ty-y^TK(\alpha+h)+yTy
\\
=&\alpha^T K^TK\alpha + h^T K^TK\alpha+\alpha^T K^TKh+h^T K^TKh
\\
-&\alpha^TK^Ty-h^TK^Ty -y^TK\alpha-h^TK\alpha+y^TKy
\\
=&F(\alpha)+ \underbrace{h^T K^TK\alpha+\alpha^T K^TKh-h^TK^Ty -h^TK\alpha}_{DF(\alpha)\cdot h} +{h^T K^TKh}
\end{align}
Recall that $\alpha^TK^TKh=h^T(\alpha^TK^TK)^T=h^TK^T(\alpha^TK^T)^T=h^TK^TK\alpha$. We have 
\begin{align}
DF(\alpha)\cdot h
=& h^T K^TK\alpha+\alpha^T K^TKh-h^TK^Ty -h^TK\alpha
\\
=& h^T K^TK\alpha+h^TK^TK\alpha-h^TK^Ty -h^TK\alpha
\\
=&h^T(2K^TK\alpha-Ky-K\alpha)
\end{align}
Then $F(\alpha)=0$ if, only if, $\alpha$ is solution of linear system 
$$
(2K^TK-K)\alpha=ky
$$
If there is $(2K^TK-K)^{-1}$ then 
$$
\alpha=(2K^TK-K)^{-1}Ky.
$$

Comment: Looks like the $\lambda \alpha^T K \alpha$ term escaped, the $y^T y$ term temporarily became invisible and the expected $y^T K h$ term auto-transformed to $h^T K \alpha$.